# Running A timer when application quits

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iphone development. I want to develop a multi-timezone enabled alarm clock which can be run on iphone. But i'm not sure whether it is possible to run a timer in the background even if the application quits.
 If not then is there any other way to do that.

Looking forwadr to any kind of help.

Thanks in advance
Koushik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to run anything in the background. But you could save the start date etc. on the device and read it at the next start. This is obviously not exactly what you want, because the timer could already been run out at the next start. This is your only option it seems.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But if it is not possible then how the available alarm clock applications for iphone were developed. There must be some way. Can you please help me on that.

Comment: The only way to get into the App Store is using Push notifications. Have a look at Josh's answer.